# Split AndroidStudio's XML/Text and Design Window

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-layout-editor

Currently, Android Studio shows XML and Design windows as a Tabbed option. I want the windows as the following.

[image]

I have Split the windows, but when I change on the left side then no changes made on the right side until I focused(click) on the right side. It will save my time.

As you can see in the picture, I have made changes to Button's text but the right side is not showing the changes. It required the focus(click) to update the changes. **(I mean changes will appear once I click on the right side)**

Comment: It may be possible your AS getting to much load so please check your system specification or restart your system check again also update your AS if you using older one. (Latest AS version is 2.2.3)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**There is not need to split the screen vertically.**

You just need to click on **Preview** option which on right side while you are in **Text** mode.

[image]

Comment: Same problem. How to enable the preview. I cant see mine preview button ?

Comment: In image if see right side there is preview image, see the image I posted the red rectangle

Comment: Man I'm not the OP. I have same problem same day ago I disabled my preview, but dont know how to enable ?

Comment: for the layout file go in text mode like above image then you will get preview button to the right side

Comment: @NJ can you explain why are you using `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` instead of direct EditText?

Comment: @Nothing if have any query  ask new question.